# c# Generics for Attribute helper methods

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I cannot find a good way to make this DRY in .Net Core. (Dont repeat yourself). How can I make it so I'm not repeating majority of the logic? Here are the 2 methods:

```
    public static string GetCategory(this Enum val)
    {
        CategoryAttribute[] attributes = (CategoryAttribute[])val
            .GetType()
            .GetField(val.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CategoryAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Category : string.Empty;
    }


    public static string GetDescription(this Enum val)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])val
            .GetType()
            .GetField(val.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Is this .NET Framework or .NET Standard/Core?

Comment: Replace the attribute types with a `TAttribute` type parameter. Add an accessor Func as a parameter to the helper, instead of trying to retrieve the property directly, eg `Func<TAttribute,TResult> selector` and pass `att=>att.Description` when you call the helper

Comment: @Haytam This is .net Core.

Comment: `...This is .net Core.` <= then definitely tag it as such.

Comment: This is already DRY.  However, I like the answer that StriplingWarrior posted below.

Comment: You could also use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattributes?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start with this:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this Enum val)
    where T : Attribute
{
    return (T)val
    .GetType()
    .GetField(val.ToString())
    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), false);
}
```

Which turns your methods into this:

```
public static string GetCategory(this Enum val)
{
    return val.GetAttribute<CategoryAttribute>()?.Category ?? string.Empty;
}


public static string GetDescription(this Enum val)
{
    return val.GetAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? string.Empty;
}
```

You could arguably do more to make those final methods a little more DRY, but I'm guessing the pattern that you're using here (getting a property from an attribute and returning its value or an empty string) probably isn't common enough to be worth creating a method specifically for that. The `GetAttribute` method, on the other hand, is likely to be a lot more reusable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generic version of [`GetCustomAttribute<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.8) instead which simplifies the code enough to where another abstraction is not necessary IMO.

```
public static string GetCategory(this Enum val)
{
    return val.GetType()
          .GetField(val.ToString())
          .GetCustomAttribute<CategoryAttribute>(false)?.Category ?? string.Empty;
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum val)
{
    return val.GetType()
          .GetField(val.ToString())
          .GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(false)?.Description ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Remember to pass `false` into that method, to maintain the behavior of the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Igor. I'm going to go with StriplingWarrior answer. If another helper method is added his would require less code. Yours is a valid answer too.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.3, you can constraint your methods to enum types.
This will save you one boxing of your enum.

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static string GetCategory<T>(this T val) where T: Enum
    {
        return GetAttr<CategoryAttribute, T>(val)?.Category ?? "";
    }

    public static string GetDescription<T>(this T val) where T : Enum
    {
        return GetAttr<DescriptionAttribute, T>(val)?.Description ?? "";
    }

    private static TAttr GetAttr<TAttr, T>(this T val) where TAttr : Attribute
    {
        return (TAttr)typeof(T)
            .GetField(val.ToString())
            ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false)
            ?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Also, when working with reflection, it is important to cache for performance:

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    private class EnumMetadata
    {
        public CategoryAttribute CategoryAttribute { get; set; }
        public DescriptionAttribute DescriptionAttribute { get; set; }
    }

    private class EnumMetadataCache<T> where T : Enum
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<T, EnumMetadata> MetadataCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, EnumMetadata>();

        public static EnumMetadata GetMetadata(T item)
        {
            return MetadataCache.GetOrAdd(item, val =>
                new EnumMetadata
                {
                    CategoryAttribute = GetAttr<CategoryAttribute, T>(val),
                    DescriptionAttribute = GetAttr<DescriptionAttribute, T>(val)
                }
            );
        }
    }

    public static string GetCategory<T>(this T val) where T : Enum
    {
        return EnumMetadataCache<T>.GetMetadata(val).CategoryAttribute?.Category ?? "";
    }

    public static string GetDescription<T>(this T val) where T : Enum
    {
        return EnumMetadataCache<T>.GetMetadata(val).DescriptionAttribute?.Description ?? "";
    }

    private static TAttr GetAttr<TAttr, T>(this T val) where TAttr : Attribute
    {
        return (TAttr)typeof(T)
            .GetField(val.ToString())
            ?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttr), false)
            ?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```